# Change database during play auto-test

Tags: java, database, playframework, autotest

I need to change database during test execution.
I am first connected to the test database, but at some point I want to connect to another database (external one perhaps), and perform some other tests.
Is this possible? If yes, how?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I'm using Play 1.2.5

Answer (score 0):

If you use JUnit to test, you can make an external config ( file or whatever you want ) refered via parameter and run 2 separate test with 2 config with 2 different string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest adding following snippet to `build.sbt`:

   ```
   val testConfig = "-Dconfig.file=conf/" + Option(System.getProperty("test.config")).getOrElse("application") + ".conf"
   ```

   Now you can invoke your tests from console as following:

   ```
   activator -Dtest.config="another_conf" test
   ```

   `another_conf` defines test datasource.
   This approach gives flexibility. You can specify different configuration for your local tests as  remote (if CI is involved).
2. Pass extra configuration to `fakeApplication()` method.